# Cannot click on link using Selenium / Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, random

I have some code that navigates to a specific website and click through some links.   I’m encountering an issue with a certain element (1301 - Front Seat Tracks and Motors) where my code recognizes the element but is not able to click the link.  The code recognizes the element b/c the webpage moves to that link when I step through the code.

https://epc.tesla.com/en-US/catalogs/2

Since I’m stepping through the code which allows me to wait until the page loads, I know it is not a timing issue.  I used WebDriverWait and that did not work. I tried click(), submit(), sendkeys() methods without any success.  Chrome and Edge browsers give me the same issue.

I use the same line of code to click through other elements on the page without any issues.  What is causing my below code to recognize this specific element but not click through?

```
from random import randint
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver

# Open webpage to retrieve scraping parameters
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
URL = 'https://epc.tesla.com/en-US/catalogs/2/'
browser.get(URL)

sleep(randint(5,7))

# Locate element and click on link (can locate but cannot click link)
LinkClick = browser.find_element('xpath','/html/body/app-root/div[1]/main/app-catalog/div/div/section/ul/li[4]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]').click()
```

Note: My original code has variables in the LinkClick code so hard coding it to a certain name is not ideal.

Comment: Try the CSS selector, `section a` instead. It's a much cleaner way to get to the links you want and is infinitely less brittle than an XPath that starts with `/html`. Also, you'd be clicking on the A tag (link) instead of an LI tag of unknown size.

Comment: Also, we can't tell you what's wrong with your script when you haven't provided it. Take your current script, reduce it down to a [mcve], and post it in your question.

Comment: @jeff - done!  editted code for clarity.  Let me take a look at CSS selector method!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After conducting a re-review of the provided code, I have reevaluated the issue associated with the driver.windowmaximize() function.

Upon further examination, I have identified that the root cause lies in the XPath expression utilized in the provided program. The xpath has been derived from the **li tag**. It is suggested that the XPath should be derived from the [**anchor tag**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OT4Lc.png) for more precise targeting.

This strategic modification is likely to resolve the issue encountered during the program's execution, even if the `browser.maximize_window()` function is not used.

So, you can use either of the two XPath expressions given below:

```
xpath_expression = "//a[normalize-space()='1301 - Front Seat Tracks and Motors']"
```

or

```
  xpath_expression = "/html/body/app-root/div[1]/main/app-catalog/div/div/section/ul/li[4]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a"
```

Comment: TY for your response!  I was missing "/a" after my locator.  Once i modified my code, i was able to click the link through to the next page.  TY again for your quick follow up and continuing support!  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

When you are clicking on element generally try to see for tag as 'a' or 'button' or 'input'. Here there is tag with a below li.

Also you have to use some advanced xpath to find element.

Use this xpath: //a[contains(text(), '1301 - Front Seat Tracks and Motors')]

```
LinkClick = WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//a[contains(text(), '1301 - Front Seat Tracks and Motors')]'))).click()
```

Comment: Your code gave me an error.  I think the single quote placement is not right.  Also, hard coding it to a fixed name is not ideal.

Comment: I also revised my code to remove the webdriver wait in my updated post.  This should help with isolating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Upon reviewing the provided code, I encountered an issue similar to the one previously mentioned. To resolve this, I made adjustments to the code by introducing `driver.maximize_window()` and incorporating **explicit waits**. This decision was driven by the recognition that sometimes the browser window's size can impact the visibility and interaction with elements on the webpage.

In instances where the browser window is not maximized, elements may extend beyond the viewport boundaries, rendering them inaccessible for interaction, such as clicking. Maximizing the window can bring more elements into the viewport, making them accessible for interaction.

Additionally It is noteworthy that the line of code in question,

```
LinkClick = browser.find_element('xpath','/html/body/app-root/div[1]/main/app-catalog/div/div/section/ul/li[4]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]').click()
```

while syntactically correct,but is not recommended for use due to several reasons. Instead, it is advisable to modify the code as follows:

```
link_element = browser.find_element('xpath', '/html/body/app-root/div[1]/main/app-catalog/div/div/section/ul/li[4]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]')
link_element.click()
```

This revised approach involves separating the find_element and click actions into distinct lines. This not only adheres to best coding practices but also enhances the readability of the code.

The revised code is as follows:

```
from random import randint
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

# Open the webpage to retrieve scraping parameters
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
URL = 'https://epc.tesla.com/en-US/catalogs/2/'
browser.get(URL)

# Maximize the browser window for better visibility of elements
browser.maximize_window()

# Introduce a random wait time
sleep(randint(5, 7))

# Locate the element with explicit wait for clickability
xpath_expression = '/html/body/app-root/div[1]/main/app-catalog/div/div/section/ul/li[4]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]'
link_element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath_expression)))

# Click on the located link
link_element.click()

time.sleep(10)
```

If you would like to conduct a hands-on test, I have created a test case using Test Assist, a no-code Selenium editor. Feel free to review and execute the test case by clicking on the following link:
https://app.testassist.dev/program/67e2f123-7e84-47f3-a2fb-6250fed296c0

Comment: noted on seperating the click function apart from the xpath locator.  Thanks the clarity on proper usage!

Comment: maximizing the browser window worked for that specific element!  But unfortunately for the next element, the same code will not click the link if the window is maximized.  Funny enough, the code will click the specifc element (link) if the window is not maximized.

Comment: I'm not sure if "element_to_be_clickable" is working as even if it's not clickable, the script continues thinking that the element is clickable which then causes the rest of the process to fail.